# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (16,18,3) into shape (16)

Tags: numpy, opencv, jupyter-notebook, array-broadcasting, semantic-segmentation

I was trying to instance segment my RGB images using [pixellib](https://pixellib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Image_instance.html) library. However, I encountered the problem from segmentImage function. From stacktrace, I found the issue within init.py, and I have no idea why it needs to broadcast from 3D arrays to 1D. 20 Images from another folder I tried earlier didn't counter any of these.

P.S. This was my first question on StackOverflow. if I miss any necessary details, please let me know.

```
for file in os.listdir(test_path):        
        abs_test_path = os.path.join(test_path, file)
        if file.endswith('.jpg'):
            filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            if (os.path.isfile(abs_test_path)):
                out_path = out_seg_path + filename
                
                segment_image.segmentImage(abs_test_path, show_bboxes=True,
                                           save_extracted_objects=True, 
                                           extract_segmented_objects=True)
                im_0 = cv2.imread('segmented_object_1.jpg')
                cv2.imwrite(out_path + '_1.jpg', im_0)
    
                im_1 = cv2.imread('segmented_object_2.jpg')
                cv2.imwrite(out_path + '_2.jpg', im_1)
```

This is my error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-835299843033> in <module>
     15 
     16             segment_image.segmentImage(abs_test_path, show_bboxes=True,
---> 17                                        save_extracted_objects=True, extract_segmented_objects=True)
     18 
     19 #             segment_image.segmentImage('segmented_object_1.jpg', show_bboxes=True, output_image_name=out_path + '_1.jpg',

~\anaconda3\envs\mask_rcnn\lib\site-packages\pixellib\instance\__init__.py in segmentImage(self, image_path, show_bboxes, extract_segmented_objects, save_extracted_objects, mask_points_values, output_image_name, text_thickness, text_size, box_thickness, verbose)
    762                         cv2.imwrite(save_path, extracted_objects)
    763 
--> 764                 extracted_objects = np.array(ex, dtype=object)
    765 
    766                 if mask_points_values == True:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (16,18,3) into shape (16)
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to help you.

I don't know what `segment_image.segmentImage` is, or what it expects.  And I don't have your `jpg` file to test.

I have an idea of why the problem line raises this error, but since it occurs in an unknown function I can't suggest any fixes.

```
extracted_objects = np.array(ex, dtype=object)
```

`ex` probably is a list of arrays, arrays that match in some some dimensions but not others.  It's trying to make an object dtype array of those arrays, but due to the mix of shapes it raises an error.

An simple example that raises the same error:

```
In [151]: ex = [np.ones((3, 4, 3)), np.ones((3, 5, 3))]
In [152]: np.array(ex, object)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [152] in <module>
    np.array(ex, object)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,4,3) into shape (3,)
```

Comment: I have solved this issue. An error was raised because the function segmentImage from pixellib [link](https://pixellib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Image_instance.html) couldn't detect any pixel to segment. Maybe that's why.